# window.focus not working on already open window in firefox

Tags: jquery

My code is not working for firefox but same code is working in chrome.
Here is my code:

```
$( "#confirm" ).dialog({

        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            "Yes": function() {
                newWindow = window.open(url,"myWindow","status=1,width=870,height=530");
                newWindow.focus();

                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             }
        }
   });
```

I want to bring focus if window is already opened. But not working in firefox.

Comment: @Praveen that solution is not working in my case

Comment: Okay, what exactly is happening then?

Comment: @Praveen if you know solution, so tell me the one

Comment: above code is calling after ajax success. So, is this problem?

Comment: No that doesn't matter. What did you try? You said you saw the duplicate question and that solution isn't working. What did you try?

Comment: I have tried browser setting. But still not working

Comment: Okay, I have opened your question for answers. Let's see...

Comment: I want exact solution for this. Please help me

Comment: Yeah, fine. I am unable to help you. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Let's keep our ears open for new answers...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason current window is getting focus. To solve this problem add one more function below focus like this:

```
$( "#confirm" ).dialog({

    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

        "Yes": function() {
            newWindow = window.open(url,"myWindow","status=1,width=870,height=530");
            newWindow.focus();
            newWindow.moveTo(0,0);

            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
    }
});
```

So, add moveTo(0,0); this will bring focus again to window and doesn't effect to window.